Not able to see Enroll button on Amazon Connect CCP interface
Hi I am testing (Personal subscription) Amazon Connect to enroll the customer voice. Following the instruction given on AWS documentation.

I have created AWS Connect instance
Enabled Voice ID
Accepted BIPA Agreement

Able to transfer calls to agent but CCP interface does not show the Enroll status and button to capture the voice. Agent has been given voice id role in security profile. Despite that CCP does not show the option to enroll the voice.
Is there anything I have missed ? Any help is appreciated.
To enroll the voice is there any specific change on control flow I need to make ?

